# Unexpected Illegal Token in javascript from CDN - scripts contains only garbled text

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to host a webpage on my PC (Running Windows 7), and intend to use bootstrap css/javascript library, but I am having trouble using the bootstrap javascript library from a CDN. Here is a minimal example, index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
Hello world
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to host the page on localhost using both "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" and using node.js + express, but I get the same result, where I get the message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" with reference to bootstrap.min.js:1 in chrome's javascript/html debugger. 
If I open bootstrap.min.js it only shows lots of chinese signs (which is translated to meaningless text in google translate). All this goes for other CDN scripts also, such as socket.io.

*Edit 1:
I tried downloading the source and loading the bootstrap.min.js script locally 
with

```html
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but I get the excact same problem as before.

Comment: Have you tried to download them to your local? Maybe something about encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my own local page. I thought it might be an issue with the way I was loading bootstrap or jquery as these files were showing what looked like Chinese characters in Chrome Dev tools, even though the js and css files looked ok when loaded from a URL. Googling "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" came up with this question on Stack Overflow, so I'll answer. The issue turned out to be invalid characters in my HTML.

My method to solve was to create a dead simple page from scratch and add the features from the failing page one by one until it resembled my failing page. In the end, the source looked identical in a text editor, but the newly constructed page worked fine while and the original page had the "unexpected token" error in Chrome console. So I compared the files and found some hidden characters (which I had copy and pasted from a web page snippet) which were causing the failure.

When I copy and paste your HTML above into a text file and open it in Chrome, it displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the character coding made the same issue.
As soon as I forced the output to save as UTF-8, the issue gone.