# MarkerClusterer script: Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, html, markerclusterer

I made a project that dynamically generates an HTML page with Google Maps and MarkerClusterer and displays it within an integrated browser window -- this works just fine.

When I take the source code generated by the project and put it into an HTML file, it suddenly did not work. I started stripping it down and got to the point to where I have an empty HTML file with `MarkerClusterer` included -- which is giving an unexpected token error in the browser console.

The file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js'></script>

<title>Map</title>
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
        height: 90%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I've tried moving the script tag, using the minified version, using IE (which is what the embedded browser is), using Firefox -- none of it works.

When I attempt to view the script through chrome console to see where the problem is, it's all displayed in Chinese characters (all in one line):

[image]

Opening the file that the script is linking to works fine.

I'm really stumped here and I'm not quite sure where to go next!

[EDIT]
I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271888/unexpected-illegal-token-in-javascript-from-cdn-scripts-contains-only-garbled?rq=1) which sounds exactly like my issue, but the accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

add `charset="UTF-8"` to the script reference

it should look like this

`<script src='http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js' charset='UTF-8'></script>`

worked for me